# How to generate app bundle with signed APK for android app to be published on playstore?

Tags: android

I downloaded an **ANDROID STUDIO** to generate *APK* to android *app* bundle; however I never had the so called **GENERATE SIGNED BUNDLE/APK** under **BUILD**. What do you think should I do? Was there something wrong with the way I downloaded it or was it not the latest version of **Android Studio**?

Comment: I don't think it matters?

Comment: https://www.gsrikar.com/2019/01/how-to-generate-android-app-bundle.html follow this link

Comment: I did the steps you provided. The problem is I don't have that APP BUNDLE/APK.

Comment: There may be several reasons. But first of all click this on android studio:  "File > Sync Project with Gradle File System" and check again.